# Formatting DataBinder.Eval data

Tags: asp.net, formatting, repeater, databinder

How can I format data coming from a DataBinder.Eval statement in an ASPX page?

For example, I want to display the published date of the news items in a particular format in the homepage. I'm using the ASP.NET 2.0 Repeater control to show the list of news items.

The code for this goes like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
<HeaderTemplate><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="255"></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr><td >
            <a href='/content/latestNews.aspx?id=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>'>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNewsTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title") %>'></asp:Label>
            </a>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
           <asp:Label ID="lblNewsDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "publishedDate"))%>'></asp:Label>
    </td></tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

Is there a way I could call a custom method with the DataBinder.Eval value as its parameter (something like below)?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNewsDate" runat="server" Text='<%# GetDateInHomepageFormat(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "publishedDate")) )%>'></asp:Label>
```

If yes, then where do I write the GetDateInHomepageFormat method? I tried out in the code behind page but got a run time error?
If this is not possible, is there a way to do inline formatting?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is an optional overload for DataBinder.Eval to supply formatting:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "expression"[, "format"]) %>
```

The format parameter is a String value, using the value placeholder replacement syntax (called composite formatting) like this:

```
<asp:Label id="lblNewsDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "publishedDate", "{0:dddd d MMMM}") %>'</label>
```

Comment: great answer... also worth while to add this link for all the C# String Format for DateTime at http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Good answer, but I just want to point out that there is a missing '}'  and a extra ']' at the end of the format expression in the label sample above. It should be: ..., "{0:dddd d MMMM}") %>'</label>

Comment: Replying here because this is still high in Google results to this day. Keep in mind there is a performance penalty (because of the late binding) when using Eval.

To format output I prefer passing an explicit cast to a function, eg. <%# Format(((DeliveryDataType)Container.DataItem).DeliveryDate, "dd.MM.yy")%>

Comment: Instead of "expression"[, "format"]) it should be "expression", ["format"])

Answer (score 14):

After some searching on the Internet I found that **it is in fact very much possible** to call a custom method passing the DataBinder.Eval value.

The custom method can be written in the code behind file, but has to be declared **public** or **protected**. In my question above, I had mentioned that I tried to write the custom method in the code behind but was getting a run time error. The reason for this was that I had declared the method to be **private**.

So, in summary the following is a good way to use DataBinder.Eval value to get your desired output:

default.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNewsDate" runat="server" Text='<%# GetDateInHomepageFormat(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "publishedDate")) )%>'></asp:Label>
```

default.aspx.cs code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected string GetDateInHomepageFormat(DateTime d)
    {

        string retValue = "";

        // Do all processing required and return value

        return retValue;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 12):

Why not use the simpler syntax?

```
<asp:Label id="lblNewsDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("publishedDate", "{0:dddd d MMMM}") %>'</label>
```

This is the template control "Eval" that takes in the expression and the string format:

```
protected internal string Eval(
string expression,
string format
```

)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d2sz789.aspx

Answer (score 11):

You can use a function into a repeater like you said, but notice that the DataBinder.Eval returns an object and you have to cast it to a DateTime.

You also can format your field inline:

```
<%# ((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"publishedDate")).ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") %>
```

If you use ASP.NET 2.0 or newer you can write this as below:

```
<%# ((DateTime)Eval("publishedDate")).ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd") %>
```

Another option is to bind the value to label at OnItemDataBound event.

Answer (score 3):

This line solved my problem:

```
<%#DateTime.Parse(Eval("DDDate").ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")%>
```

Comment: @Wahab: Thats perfect as long as you are happy to do the formatting inline. However, the original question was how you could use a custom method to do the formatting. The idea being you could re-use the custom method and reduce complexity in the ASPX page. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

To format the date using the local date format use:

```
<%#((DateTime)Eval("ExpDate")).ToString("d")%>
```

[How to Format an Eval Statement to Display a Date using Date Locale](http://willmtz.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-format-eval-statement-to-display_24.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all. I had been stuck on standard format strings for some time. I also used a custom function in VB.

Mark Up:-

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" text='<%# Formatlabel(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "psWages1D")) %>'/>
```

Code behind:-

```
Public Function fLabel(ByVal tval) As String
   fLabel = tval.ToString("#,##0.00%;(#,##0.00%);Zero")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Text='<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("LastLoginDate").ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt") %>'

This works for the format as you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="ServiceBeginDate" runat="server" Text='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceBeginDate", "{0:yyyy}") == "0001") ? "" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceBeginDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Begin Date">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="ServiceBeginDate" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                                    (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceBeginDate", "{0:yyyy}")== "0001") ? 
                                    "" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceBeginDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")  %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateColumn>

Comment: This checks if the date is NULL and if its Not it formats and stores the date!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way in aspx page

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateColoumnName", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>
```