# asp.net gridview item template format currency

Tags: asp.net, gridview, format, currency, itemtemplate

> Possible duplicate [Formatting DataBinder.Eval data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275194/formatting-databinder-eval-data)

i want to change the format of an item template in a gridview, i want to show the currency..

this is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monto">
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Monto")%></ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMonto" Text='<%# Eval("Monto", "{0:C2}")%>' /><%-- Eval("Price", "{0:C2}")--%>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfooterMonto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                        
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="rfvMonto" controltovalidate="txtfooterMonto" Display="None" 
                errormessage="Monto" ValidationGroup="InsertValidationControls"/> 
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i want to set a currency format, can i do it in the "<%# Eval("Monto")%>"

Comment: In the ItemTemplate?  Yes, you should be able to do it the same way you do it in the EditItemTemplate.

Comment: i tried this "<ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Monto", "{0:n}")%></ItemTemplate>" and it works!!, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have formatting setup for editing here:  EditItemTemplate

But not for viewing here: ItemTemplate